# PySide2 UI Maya Find object names that contain specific names

Tags: qt, pyside2

I want to include in the argument an object name that contains a specific name from the ui file.

I have created pickers in QtDesigner and have imported them for Maya 2022.
It assigned a command to each button. But I realized I needed a huge number of commands.
It's just this scene.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from maya.app.general.mayaMixin import MayaQWidgetBaseMixin
import shiboken2 as shiboken

UIFILEPATH = 'D:/MAYA/pyside_pick/ui/PicsTest5.ui'

class MainWindow(MayaQWidgetBaseMixin,QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.UI = QUiLoader().load(UIFILEPATH)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.UI.windowTitle())
        self.setCentralWidget(self.UI)
        
        #PushButton
        self.UI.pushButton_sphere.clicked.connect(self.PushedCmd)
            
    #Comand  
    def PushedCmd(self):
        bTEXT = str(self.UI.pushButton_sphere.text())
        cmds.select('pSphere1')
        print(bTEXT)

def main():

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

If it is given an object name like above, it certainly works.
But there are commands that need to be directed only to objects containing "pushButton_".
I tried like this

```
button1 = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'pushButton_*')
self.button1.clicked.connect(self.testPrint)

def testPrint(self):
    print(self.button1)
```

I meant to define button1 as a QPushButton containing 'pushButton _' and print its name when clicked.
Unfortunately, I learned that asterisks can not be used as searches.
Then, I tried like this

```
button1 = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'pushButton_sphere')
self.button1.clicked.connect(self.testPrint)

def testPrint(self):
    print(self.button1)
```

The result was written as (PySide2.QtWidgets.QPushButton)already deleted.

This is probably rudimentary, but being Jap I couldn't find a workable solution.
Tell me how to output the object name when I press the button, please.
Also tell me if the notation is wrong.

Comment: You could try `for child in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QPushButton):` `if child.objectName().startswith('pushButton'):`. The reality is that you'll need to find a smarter way to *group* those buttons, either by using a QButtonGroup or by manually adding them to a data container as a list or a dict.

Comment: Thank you.
It allowed me to keep track of the number of buttons starting with 'pushButton'.
However, it was not possible to retrieve the name of the button that was clicked. I'm also currently trying eventFilter and others. I will do my best to resolve it.
Thanks.